# react : Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 5: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: nginx, reactjs

I can not understand why and what this error is there - du you know why?

Update: I am running this in an nginx docker container.

Error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Parse Error: Line 10: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

 at http://x.x.x.x/scripts/example.js:10:undefined

enter code here... R OTHER DEALINGS IN THE SOFTW
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello React</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.0/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/jsx;harmony=true" src="scripts/example.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script/example.js

```
var Simple = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return { count: 0 };
  },

  handleMouseDown: function(){
    alert('I was told: ' + this.props.message);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
  },

  render: function(){

    return <div>
      <div className="clicker" onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}>
        Give me the message!
      </div>
      <div className="message">Message conveyed
        <span className="count">{this.state.count}</span> time(s)</div>
    </div>
    ;
  }
});

React.render(<Simple message="Keep it Simple"/>,
                  document.body);
```

Comment: I put your code into a jsfiddle (with a single change of `renderComponent` => `render` to update to the latest ReactJS form), and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/smmccrohan/vmthzsj5/

Comment: Yep, thanks. I am running this in a docker container with nginx, then I get the error - hmm?

Comment: Interesting. I think your problem is in the execution environment, then. Your code on its own looks okay.

Answer (score 0):

I run in NGINX no problem, I doubt this is an issue, but you never know if it's somehow a JSX compiler issue.  Can you try the below and see if it's the same result in your environment?

```
var Simple = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return { count: 0 };
  },

  handleMouseDown: function(){
    alert('I was told: ' + this.props.message);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
  },

  render: function(){
    render (
      <div>
      <div className="clicker" onMouseDown={this.handleMouseDown}>
        Give me the message!
      </div>
      <div className="message">Message conveyed
        <span className="count">{this.state.count}</span> time(s)</div>
    </div>
     )
  }
});

React.render(<Simple message="Keep it Simple"/>,
                  document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks, this should work - it must be something nginx. When I run docker run --name webclient -v "$PWD":/usr/share/nginx/html -p 80:80 -d nginx I can then see an old index.html files in the chrome inspector. I will have to give it a rest for to day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem:
nginx was caching 
Solution:
Set nginx.conf setting to "expires off;"